# Laravel axios delete fails

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-routing, axios

Am trying to perfrom a delete request on a resource route via\

```
           this.$axios.delete("position-types", {data:this.deletedata})
                .then((res)=>{
                this.dialog = false;
                }, (err)=>{
                    this.dialog = false;
                })
```

In my routes i have

```
Route::resource('/position-types', "PositionsTypesController");
```

In my PositionTypes controller i have

```
    public function destroy(PositionsTypes $positionsTypes)
   {
    return $positionsTypes;
    //do stuff here
   }
```

When i try the above am getting an error

```
method 405 not allowed.
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using resource controllers for delete you will have url like so:

```
/position-types/{id}
```

so in axios you probably run it like this:

```
 this.$axios.delete("position-types/2", {data:this.deletedata})
                .then((res)=>{
                this.dialog = false;
                }, (err)=>{
                    this.dialog = false;
                })
```

to delete resource with id 2

Remember - you can always run:

```
php artisan route:list
```

to verify what routes are defined in your application